# Cocoa And Swift - I want to make a simple rest API call using Swift 4 and Cocoa for Mac OS Application

Tags: cocoa, swift4

Can anyone suggest me how to make a rest api call for Mac OS Application using Swift 4 And Cocoa. I tried lots of ways but unable to make the api call.

Here is the code:

```
func callAPI(){

    let AuthorizationToken = "Basic mykey="
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://myipaddress/api/Batch")!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue(AuthorizationToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        //print(response!)
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
            print(json)
            self.ApiValue.stringValue = "Success"
        } catch {
            print("error")
            self.ApiValue.stringValue = "Error"
        }
    })

    task.resume()

}
```

[See the info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1xvr.png)

Comment: @Moritz , "Thread 6: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" I am getting this exception.

Comment: If `data` is `nil` then `error` is not `nil`. Handle the error and print it. And in the `catch` clause print also the `error` instance rather than a meaningless literal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. In new update of swift the NSAppTransportSecurity configuration is needed. I added following code to my info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then also have to allow the network incoming and outgoing connection in AppSandBox->Capabilities, then all set.

Answer (score 3):

**in Xcode 11 .1 +**

Set Capabilities - Under App Sandbox - Check both Incoming Connects and Outgoing Connections:

[image]

You can try this code to check in your viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/")!

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            if error != nil || data == nil {
                print("Client error!")
                return
            }


            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I could not find this(App Sandbox) option in Xcode 11.x

Answer (score 0):

`data` from server side is `nil`, that's why you get error like

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It's not a good idea to use force unwrapping for Optional value

I've tested your code and see issue:

> Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

You can fix it with adding this code into plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

More info you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

I've tested code with updating of plist file and got this json from server side without any errors:

```
{
        batchID = BA000000015;
        code = 2015;
        coordinatorName = "<null>";
        createdBy = Suc19320182015;
        createdByID = LU000000011;
        createdOn = "2018-08-14T06:37:43";
        endDate = "2018-08-14T00:00:00";
        name = SSDG;
        schoolID = BS00001;
        startDate = "2018-08-14T00:00:00";
        status = 1;
        updatedBy = Suc19320182015;
        updatedOn = "2018-08-14T06:37:51";
    }
```

Comment: I have added this above code to my info.plist but don't know why still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding an image link of info.plist you can check that.

Comment: I don't know where is your mistake because your code is correct with plist file. I've checked again and code is working as expected (Mac OS Application using Swift 4.1 and Xcode 10)

Comment: Ohh, May be some thing else is happening, I will check it out again.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a temporary hack, just delete the NSExceptionDomains key and everything underneath it.  Then re-test and see if it works.

Please keep in mind, this completely disables the ATS security and it's not recommended.  Realistically, you should have a proper domain for your server and reference it with the correct domain in the NSExceptionDomains key (instead of the example.com).

Comment: Actually I have inserted my server IP address instead of that example.com , is it ok ?

Comment: I don't have any domain in my server instead of APIs

Comment: Did you try without a NSExceptionDomains key?  Did it work?  Then, you can try to enter an ip address but I'm not sure that will work.  The documentation seems to imply an ip address wouldn't work but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I tried without a NSExceptionDomains key, but still it was showing exception releted to domain.